# Circular queue, how to print values using java

Tags: java

How to print values of circular queue
using java
Im getting output as null and expected output is 5,4,3,2,1. PLease help me.
I'm don't know what is wrong.

```
public class Main
{
    public static class Node{
        public static int data;
        public static Node next;
    }
    public static Node front = null, rear = null;
    public static void enqueue(int data){
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.data = data;
        if(front == null){
            front = temp;
        }
        else{
            rear.next = temp;
        }
        rear = temp;
        rear.next = front;
    }
    public static void displayQueue(){
        Node temp = front;
        while (temp.next != front) {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        enqueue(5);
        enqueue(4);
        enqueue(3);
        enqueue(2);
        enqueue(1);
        displayQueue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `enqueue` is working correctly?

Comment: Ig the problem is with that. I tried printing front and rear what it showed is 1,1, so initialization of front is false. I don't understand what's wrong with enqueue

Answer (score 0):

You should study how static works... when you make something static it only has one value, so basically you are just modifying always the same value.

You also don't show all the values, you forget to show one in the loop, so the only value you have you dont show :(

Try this code, solves most of your problem

```
public class Main{
    public static class Node{
        public int data;
        public Node next;
    }
    public static Node front = null, rear = null;
    public static void enqueue(int data){
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.data = data;
        if(front == null){
            front = temp;
        }
        else{
            rear.next = temp;
        }
        rear = temp;
        rear.next = front;
    }
    public static void displayQueue(){
        Node temp = front;
        while (temp.next != front) {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        enqueue(5);
        enqueue(4);
        enqueue(3);
        enqueue(2);
        enqueue(1);
        displayQueue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i see....Thanks buddy!

Comment: please accept the answer using the green mark by the up-down arrows

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.